# Ember spectrum color picker (change background)

Tags: jquery, ember.js, color-picker, spectrum

I am strulling for a while to make this component working: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-spectrum-color-picker

Code so far:

```
import SpectrumColorPickerComponent from 'ember-spectrum-color-picker/components/spectrum-color-picker';

export default SpectrumColorPickerComponent.extend({
  showInitial: true,
  moveFiresChange: true,
  showAlpha: true,
  showInput: true,
  move: function(color){
    $('#result').css('background-color',color.toRgbString());
  }
});

    <div id="result">Lorem dipsum lalala</div>
Background{{spectrum-color-picker color=result}}
```

How could I make this work?
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3zb1poh3/

Comment: Are you using ember-cli?

Comment: That's right. Ember CLI :).